Trouble with CS50 filter-less (blur) code works on an image but only passes 1/5 checks
I have a problem with the function blur in the Filter assignment of CS50.
I've been stuck with the same error messages and wondering if someone can help point out what I'm missing.
Currently the code does blur an image but the only check the code passes is regarding the corner pixels, by that logic i am finding it hard to understand why the edge and middle pixels would not work.
I am very new to programming so forgive the repeated code i'm sure there is a better way to approach this but i would first like to see if i can get this method to pass the checks after making it this far into it.
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    float count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
            // check that the + 1's and - 1's won't take loop out of bounds
            // left bottom corner (/4)
            if (i + 1 == height && j - 1 < 0)
            {
                count = 4.0;
                // red
                copy[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed +
                                      image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed)  / count;
                // green
                copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen +
                                        image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen)  / count;
                // blue
                copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue +
                                       image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue)  / count;
            }
            // right top corner
            else if (i - 1 < 0 && j + 1 == width)
            {
                count = 4.0;
                // red
                copy[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed +
                                      image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed)  / count;
                // green
                copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen +
                                        image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen)  / count;
                // blue
                copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue +
                                       image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue)  / count;
            }
            // right bottom corner
            else if (i + 1 == height && j + 1 == width)
            {
                count = 4.0;
                // red
                copy[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed +
                                      image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed)  /
                                      count;
                // green
                copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen +
                                        image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen)  / c
                                        ount;
                // blue
                copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue +
                                       image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue)  /
                                       count;
            }
            // left top corner
            else if (i - 1 < 0 && j - 1 < 0)
            {
                count = 4.0;
                // red
                copy[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed +
                                      image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed)  /
                                      count;
                // green
                copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen +
                                        image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen)  /
                                        count;
                // blue
                copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue +
                                       image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue)  /
                                       count;
            }
            // left edge (/6)
            else if (j - 1 < 0)
            {
                count = 6.0;
                // red
                copy[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed +
                                      image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed +
                                      image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed)  /
                                      count;
                // green
                copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen +
                                        image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen +
                                        image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen +
                                        image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen)  / count;
                // blue
                copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue +
                                       image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue +
                                       image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue)  /
                                       count;
            }
            // right edge
            else if (j + 1 == width)
            {
                count = 6.0;
                // red
                copy[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed +
                                      image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed +
                                      image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed)  /
                                      count;
                // green
                copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen +
                                        image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen +
                                        image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen)  /
                                        count;
                // blue
                copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue +
                                       image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue +
                                       image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue)  /
                                       count;
            }
            // top edge
            else if (i - 1 < 0)
            {
                count = 6.0;
                // red
                copy[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed +
                                      image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed +
                                      image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed)  /
                                      count;
                // green
                copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen +
                                        image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen +
                                        image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen)  /
                                        count;
                // blue
                copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue +
                                       image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue +
                                       image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue)  /
                                       count;
            }
            // bottom edge
            else if (i + 1 == height)
            {
                count = 6.0;
                // red
                copy[i][j].rgbtRed = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed +
                                      image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed +
                                      image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed)  /
                                      count;
                // green
                copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen +
                                        image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen +
                                        image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen)  /
                                        count;
                // blue
                copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue +
                                       image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue +
                                       image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue)  /
                                       count;
            }
            else
            {
                count = 9.0;
                // red
                copy[i][j].rgbtRed =
                    (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j].rgbtRed +
                     image[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + image[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed +
                     image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed +
                     image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed)  / count;
                // green
                copy[i][j].rgbtGreen =
                    (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen +
                     image[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen +
                     image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen +
                     image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen)  / count;
                // blue
                copy[i][j].rgbtBlue =
                    (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue +
                     image[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue +
                     image[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue +
                     image[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) / count;
            }

            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(copy[i][j].rgbtRed);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(copy[i][j].rgbtGreen);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(copy[i][j].rgbtBlue);
        }
    }
    return;
}


check50 error messages:
:( blur correctly filters middle pixel
    expected "127 140 149\n", not "145 160 169\n"

:( blur correctly filters pixel on edge
    expected "80 95 105\n", not "90 106 116\n"
:) blur correctly filters pixel in corner

:( blur correctly filters 3x3 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "70 85 95\n90 1..."

:( blur correctly filters 4x4 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "70 85 95\n90 1..."


What happened when you tested the routine yourself with your own 3×3 images? Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Don't immediately worry about repeating blocks of code when writing a program for the first time. Just make sure your code is readable. You are writing code, not a poem. Get it working correctly, then you can refactor your code into functions, etc.. as you see fit. It is an iterative process. You may rewrite the same code ten times when starting out. As you gain more experience, the number of iterations go down, but are never completely eliminated.

Side note: You will get more detailed information about the error if you follow the link provided by the CS50 program check50.

&& j - 1 < 0 Why don't you use the much simpler && j == 0? Your version is confusing as it looks as if there were smaller values that would cause you to enter that if block.

The assignment contains the following hint:

When implementing the blur function, you might find that blurring one pixel ends up affecting the blur of another pixel. It might be best to create a copy of image by declaring a new, two-dimensional array with code like RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];. Then copy image into copy, pixel by pixel, with nested for loops, like so:
[code omitted]

If you follow this hint, then the entire image should be copied before processing any pixels.
Alternatively, instead of following this hint, you can write the results to a separate array, and when you are finished processing all pixels, you can copy these results back to image.
However, you appear to be doing neither of the above. Instead, you do the following:

Instead of copying the entire image before procesing any pixels, you only copy a single pixel before processing that pixel. However, this copy has no effect, because you immediately overwrite the copy with something else.
You write the blurred pixel value result to copy, and then write this value back to image. As described above, this would be a viable solution if you first write all results to copy and then afterwards copy these results to image (although in that case, you should probably rename the array from copy to results, because copy is a misleading name). However, this is not what you are doing. Instead, you are immediately writing the result to image, which will affect the blur calculations of other pixels. This is wrong, because you must use the original pixel values for calculating the blur of all pixels.

Another issue is that calling round on an integer is not meaningful. You should call round on the result of the division (which is of type float) before this result is converted to an integer.

"should call round on the result of the division (which is of type float) " --> even better, call lroundf().  This avoid the promotion to double and handles the conversion from floating point.

or skip FP math with  int cont = ...; ... int average = (sum + count/2)/count; or the like.

@chux: Yes, the function lroundf may be slightly better. However, the CS50 course simply uses the function round for everything, and the assignment contains a hint for the grayscale part of the assignment to use the function round. Therefore, I don't want to confuse OP by recommending a different function.

thanks for your comments everyone. You have given me much to think about and i appreciate it!

Thanks for your replies everyone, I took on the advice of @Andreas Wenzel and re-read hint in the question. Implemented by making a nested loop just for the copy array and moved all the other code to another nested for loop. I also applied the cast to float and round functions within the loop and removed the section at the bottom of the loop where I reassign the values from "copy" to "image".
Code now passes all the checks.
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        // check that the + 1's and - 1's won't take loop out of bounds
        // left bottom corner (/4)
        if (i + 1 == height && j - 1 < 0)
        {
            count = 4.0;
            // red
            image[i][j].rgbtRed =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i - 1][j].rgbtRed +
                               copy[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + copy[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) /
                      count);
            // green
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen +
                               copy[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + copy[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) /
                      count);
            // blue
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue +
                               copy[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + copy[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) /
                      count);
        }
        // right top corner
        else if (i - 1 < 0 && j + 1 == width)
        {
            count = 4.0;
            // red
            image[i][j].rgbtRed =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i + 1][j].rgbtRed +
                               copy[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + copy[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed) /
                      count);
            // green
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen +
                               copy[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + copy[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) /
                      count);
            // blue
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue +
                               copy[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + copy[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) /
                      count);
        }
        // right bottom corner
        else if (i + 1 == height && j + 1 == width)
        {
            count = 4.0;
            // red
            image[i][j].rgbtRed =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i - 1][j].rgbtRed +
                               copy[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + copy[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed) /
                      count);
            // green
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen +
                               copy[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + copy[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) /
                      count);
            // blue
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue +
                               copy[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + copy[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) /
                      count);
        }
        // left top corner
        else if (i - 1 < 0 && j - 1 < 0)
        {
            count = 4.0;
            // red
            image[i][j].rgbtRed =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i + 1][j].rgbtRed +
                               copy[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + copy[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) /
                      count);
            // green
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen +
                               copy[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + copy[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) /
                      count);
            // blue
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue +
                               copy[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + copy[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) /
                      count);
        }
        // left edge (/6)
        else if (j - 1 < 0)
        {
            count = 6.0;
            // red
            image[i][j].rgbtRed =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i + 1][j].rgbtRed +
                               copy[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i][j + 1].rgbtRed +
                               copy[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + copy[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) /
                      count);
            // green
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen +
                               copy[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen +
                               copy[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + copy[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) /
                      count);
            // blue
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue +
                               copy[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue +
                               copy[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + copy[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) /
                      count);
        }
        // right edge
        else if (j + 1 == width)
        {
            count = 6.0;
            // red
            image[i][j].rgbtRed =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i + 1][j].rgbtRed +
                               copy[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i][j - 1].rgbtRed +
                               copy[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + copy[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed) /
                      count);
            // green
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen +
                               copy[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen +
                               copy[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + copy[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) /
                      count);
            // blue
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue +
                               copy[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue +
                               copy[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + copy[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) /
                      count);
        }
        // top edge
        else if (i - 1 < 0)
        {
            count = 6.0;
            // red
            image[i][j].rgbtRed =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i + 1][j].rgbtRed +
                               copy[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + copy[i][j - 1].rgbtRed +
                               copy[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + copy[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed) /
                      count);
            // green
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen +
                               copy[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen +
                               copy[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + copy[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) /
                      count);
            // blue
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue +
                               copy[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue +
                               copy[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + copy[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) /
                      count);
        }
        // bottom edge
        else if (i + 1 == height)
        {
            count = 6.0;
            // red
            image[i][j].rgbtRed =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i - 1][j].rgbtRed +
                               copy[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + copy[i][j - 1].rgbtRed +
                               copy[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + copy[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed) /
                      count);
            // green
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen +
                               copy[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen +
                               copy[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + copy[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) /
                      count);
            // blue
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue +
                               copy[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue +
                               copy[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + copy[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) /
                      count);
        }
        else
        {
            count = 9.0;
            // red
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(
                (float) (copy[i][j].rgbtRed + copy[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + copy[i - 1][j].rgbtRed +
                         copy[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + copy[i][j - 1].rgbtRed +
                         copy[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + copy[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed +
                         copy[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + copy[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed) /
                count);
            // green
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen +
                               copy[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + copy[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen +
                               copy[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + copy[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen +
                               copy[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + copy[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen +
                               copy[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) /
                      count);
            // blue
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue =
                round((float) (copy[i][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue +
                               copy[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + copy[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue +
                               copy[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + copy[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue +
                               copy[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + copy[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue +
                               copy[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) /
                      count);
        }
    }
}
}


The roundf() function rounds floats without having to cast. You should never cast unless you absolutely know what you are doing and why you are doing it. When you cast, you tell the compiler - don't worry about checking the type here, I know best. That will mask compiler warnings that are very important to you as a programmer. Which also bring up the point to always compile with full warnings enabled and don't accept code until it compiles without warning. (for gcc/clang that's -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow and for VS /W3 will do. Glad you got your code sorted out.

If you find the previous comment by someone else confusing, then you don't have to worry about such things until you have gained more experience, despite the advice in that comment being good. The CS50 course simply recommends that you use round without having to worry about all of the different variations of that function. Also, the Makefile provided by the distribution code of CS50 handles all of the command-line arguments of the compiler, so you don't have to worry about them either, for now.
